# How to use image file as launch image in xcode without change it name to "Default.png" and re-import it to project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6

In Xcode->Choose Project->Summary there are launch images setting which use these names:
Default.png, Default-Portrait@2x.png, Default-Portrait.png, Default-Landscape@2x.png, Default-Landscape.png, Default@2x.png. How can I add existing images but with some extra prefix to those names, e.g: Project1Default.png? 
Also, xcode forces to rename added launch images and add them to base directory of program, how can I remain them in their old resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your project's Info.plist

```
Launch image (iPhone)      DEFAULT_NAME
```

where DEFAULT_NAME is the name of the launch image. It also must be added to project.

for example, if i have added image named def@2x.png i write:

```
Launch image (iPhone)      def
```